# set kms specific resolution at boot time

Tags: ubuntu, tty, resolution, kubuntu, kms

i'm trying to set a specific resolution for kms, at boot time.
by default kms choose the highest resolution available (2500x1600) which is a bit hard to read.
i'd like to set 1440x900 instead.

i tried two things via grub, the first one:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1440x900
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1440x900
```

but that didn't help, the system act just the same, no matter if it is there or not, it just continue to use 2500x1600.

the other thing i tried instead is setting a kernel parameter like so:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="video=1440x900"
```

that kind of helped a bit, the resolution changed, it's much better and readable but then, the virtual_size didn't change accordingly, it's still 2500x1600, meaning my tty is much bigger than the screen itself and so i only see the upper_left part of a larger term.

how can i force kms to a specific resolution ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

First check which modes are supported (BIOS Users only): use Grub2 shell, (press ‘c’ on Grub2 menu), then run following commands and pick suitable mode.

```
set pager=1
insmod vbe
vbeinfo
```

Then set the mode in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1280x1024x32
```