# I get a black screen when booting using a 5.0+ kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, linux-kernel

For some reason I can't boot into any distro that uses a kernel that's 5.0+. I always get a black screen.

But I can boot if I use the nomodeset flag, but I get a very low resolution.

I am also able to boot using custom kernels like ZEN, Liquorix and Xanmod, but not all distros support those.

Similair question (probably the same problem cuz I also run an Intel integrated GPU)
[Arch linux boot goes into black screen on laptop with Intel HD onboard graphics](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335676/arch-linux-boot-goes-into-black-screen-on-laptop-with-intel-hd-onboard-graphics)

Sorry If I didn't give enough info.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a lower resolution:

- [set kms specific resolution at boot time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/520789/set-kms-specific-resolution-at-boot-time)
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_mode_setting#Forcing_modes_and_EDID

If that doesn't help you could try booting with `nomodeset`, then after the boot has completed invoke `sudo modprobe i915` or whatever graphics driver you have and if your screen immediately turns black, then SSH to your device remotely and check `dmesg` for any errors.